# Facebook Login Getting Username,But Profile email Showing Null from my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.1

Iam using facebook Login in my android app.

1.it fetching and showing the Username fine, but **email id** of the user is Showing null.

2.how to get user Email id,anyone help me to solve this issue,thanks in Advance.

[Link i reffered](http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private Button postImageBtn;
    private Button updateStatusBtn;

    private TextView userName;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions","email");

    private static String message = "Sample status posted from android app";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);



        loginBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb);
        loginBtn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","user_photos")); 
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) 
            {
                if (user != null) {
                    userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());








                } else {
                    userName.setText("You are not logged");
                     Log.i("Not available", "No Facebook user");
                }
            }
        });

        postImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        postImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                postImage();
            }
        });

        updateStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_status);
        updateStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        buttonsEnabled(false);
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened())
            {
                buttonsEnabled(true);
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");

                getUserData(session,state);




            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                buttonsEnabled(false);
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
            }
        }
    };

    public void buttonsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        postImageBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        updateStatusBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    public void postImage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            uploadRequest.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public void postStatusMessage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null)
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Status updated successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null) 
        {

            return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public void requestPermissions()
    {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null)
            s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this,PERMISSIONS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }



    private void getUserData(Session session, SessionState state)
    {
        if (state.isOpened())
        {
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            String name = user.getName();
                            // If you asked for email permission
                            String email = (String) user.getProperty("email");


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + " Email: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Exception e");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why downvoted my question?

Comment: Read the documentation first before posting anything here, Facebook has clearly mentioned that in its document, EMAIL has user's own permissions, if the EMAIL is not public, you will get null in response

Comment: then how to login from android app using Facebook,without getting user Email.

Comment: Read here! https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016
And if your question is not ambiguous, You should know, that the user account with which you are logging in on your App, must have its email  - PUBLIC

Comment: i used previously same code email id is shown now, i tried many examples not getting the email.any other alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the perfect solution for my Question. Below Added code Working Perfect.

[Link i referred](http://www.learn2crack.com/2015/06/android-facebook-sdk-implementation.html#)

MainActivity.class

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphRequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView;
import com.facebook.share.model.ShareLinkContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button share,details;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    LoginButton login;
    ProfilePictureView profile;
    Dialog details_dialog;
    TextView details_txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
        details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
        details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
        details_txt = (TextView)details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                details_dialog.show();
            }
        });


        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    profile.setProfileId(null);
                }
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
                shareDialog.show(content);

            }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                    RequestData();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });

    }
    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                        details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                        profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Xml

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="200sp"/>

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:text="Show details"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:text="Share"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:
change your AppId from Developer site

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.newdemoappbook"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

            <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider4427**********"
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                android:exported="true"/>

            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">NewDemoAppbook</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">**********</string>

</resources>
```

finally Download the latest SDK and add as a Library in Your Eclipse.

[Download SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android)

Thank you.